# Slack bot using python makes the error during github action

Tags: python, github, bots, slack, github-actions

I am making a simple slack bot using github action:

But every time I tried to post a message to my channel, the error ocurrs

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4_distributed_mlblogbot_to_py_update.py", line 130, in <module>
    text = "{0} \n*{1}* \n<{2}|{3}> :bell:".format(today, bible1, 'https://sum.su.or.kr:8888/bible/today' , script) )
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.12/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slacker/__init__.py", line 515, in post_message
    'mrkdwn': mrkdwn,
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.12/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slacker/__init__.py", line 126, in post
    api, **kwargs
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.6.12/x64/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slacker/__init__.py", line 102, in _request
    raise Error(response.error)
slacker.Error: account_inactive
```

So everytime I try, I reinstall the app and invite my bot to mychannel
But It doesn't work

Meanwhile, In my personal python env(ex, colab) there are no errors.
Should I give up the token based BOT and get the webhook based bot?
Thank you

Comment: [`account_inactive`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test): "Authentication token is for a deleted user or workspace."

Comment: @Thomas I know, But every time I made a new auth and running github action, that error occurs. Even after change my auth

Answer (score 0):

Every time I get a new auth(ex webhooks, tokens) and I run the github action, Always failed about the auth.

The hint was my "blabla.py" and the failed alarm email
I mistakenly expose my auth(IT SHOULD BE A SECRET) and Github and slack automatically drop my auth for security issue.

So after I used secret function in Github action, It works